Making a function to apply a calculation row by row?
I have a calculation function of =((C3-B3)+(D3-C3)+(E3-D3)+(F3-E3)+(G3-F3))/5 and the results all go into one column.
But I want to apply this calculation to 117 rows of data, so I don't want to hard input this function into every cell and change the number in my results column, so is there a way to automate this? I've heard of dynamic named ranges but I don't think that's what I'm searching for. Thank you!

You can automate this calculation without manually entering the formula for each row:
Drag Formula Down: Enter the formula in the first cell of your results column, then drag the fill handle down to apply it to all 117 rows. The cell references will update automatically.

Array Formula (Google Sheets): Use an array formula to apply the calculation to all rows at once:

excel

=ARRAYFORMULA(((C3:C119-B3:B119)+(D3:D119-C3:C119)+(E3:E119-D3:D119)+(F3:F119-E3:E119)+(G3:G119-F3:F119))/5)

These methods will efficiently automate your calculations.

Thank you so much! Follow up - Do you know if round can be used with array formula in any way? I keep getting an error saying I have the wrong number of arguments for ARRAYFORMULA if i try to put in ROUND at the beginning of my calculation.

First, you can simplify your formula to:
=(G3-B3)/5

Then, you can either fill down the column with your formula (cell addresses will adapt automatically).
If your range for results is known in advance you can use an array or dynamic formula for the entire range:
=(G3:G129-B3:B129)/5

In older versions of Excel you must first select the range for the results and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.
